# Make QGenericArgument/Q_ARG from QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, dbus, qvariant

I wrote an interface for [**systemd-timedated**](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated/):

```
#include <QtDBus>

#include <dbus/dbus.h>

Q_DECLARE_LOGGING_CATEGORY(timeDateInterfaceCategory)

#define TIMEDATE_DBUS_SERVICE "org.freedesktop.timedate1"
#define TIMEDATE_DBUS_PATH "/org/freedesktop/timedate1"
#define TIMEDATE_DBUS_INTERFACE "org.freedesktop.timedate1"

class TimeDateInterface
        : public QDBusAbstractInterface
{

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool CanNTP MEMBER CanNTP NOTIFY CanNTPChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool LocalRTC MEMBER LocalRTC NOTIFY LocalRTCChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool NTP MEMBER NTP NOTIFY NTPChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool NTPSynchronized MEMBER NTPSynchronized NOTIFY NTPSynchronizedChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(qulonglong RTCTimeUSec MEMBER RTCTimeUSec NOTIFY RTCTimeUSecChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(qulonglong TimeUSec MEMBER TimeUSec NOTIFY TimeUSecChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString Timezone MEMBER Timezone NOTIFY TimezoneChanged)

public :

    explicit
    TimeDateInterface(QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QDBusAbstractInterface{{TIMEDATE_DBUS_SERVICE}, {TIMEDATE_DBUS_PATH}, TIMEDATE_DBUS_INTERFACE,
                                 QDBusConnection::systemBus(),
                                 parent}
    {
        qDBusRegisterMetaType< QVariantMap >();

        if (!isValid()) {
            qCCritical(timeDateInterfaceCategory).noquote()
                    << tr("Unable to create interface %1: %2")
                       .arg(service(), lastError().message());
            return;
        }

        if (!connection().connect({service()}, path(), {DBUS_INTERFACE_PROPERTIES}, {"PropertiesChanged"},
                                  //QString::fromLatin1(QMetaObject::normalizedSignature("PropertiesChanged(QString,QVariantMap,QStringList)")),
                                  this, SLOT(propertiesChanged(QString, QVariantMap, QStringList)))) {
            Q_ASSERT(false);
        }
    }

public Q_SLOTS :

    Q_SCRIPTABLE
    void SetLocalRTC(bool localRtc, bool fixSystem, bool userInteraction)
    {
        const auto message = call(QDBus::BlockWithGui, {"SetLocalRTC"},
                                  QVariant::fromValue(localRtc),
                                  QVariant::fromValue(fixSystem),
                                  QVariant::fromValue(userInteraction));
        QDBusPendingReply<> pendingReply = message;
        Q_ASSERT(pendingReply.isFinished());
        if (pendingReply.isError()) {
            qCWarning(timeDateInterfaceCategory).noquote()
                    << tr("Asynchronous call finished with error: %1")
                       .arg(pendingReply.error().message());
            return;
        }
    }

    Q_SCRIPTABLE
    void SetNTP(bool useNtp, bool userInteraction)
    {
        const auto message = call(QDBus::BlockWithGui, {"SetNTP"},
                                  QVariant::fromValue(useNtp),
                                  QVariant::fromValue(userInteraction));
        QDBusPendingReply<> pendingReply = message;
        Q_ASSERT(pendingReply.isFinished());
        if (pendingReply.isError()) {
            qCWarning(timeDateInterfaceCategory).noquote()
                    << tr("Asynchronous call finished with error: %1")
                       .arg(pendingReply.error().message());
            return;
        }
    }

    Q_SCRIPTABLE
    void SetTime(qlonglong usecUtc, bool relative, bool userInteraction)
    {
        const auto message = call(QDBus::BlockWithGui, {"SetTime"},
                                  QVariant::fromValue(usecUtc),
                                  QVariant::fromValue(relative),
                                  QVariant::fromValue(userInteraction));
        QDBusPendingReply<> pendingReply = message;
        Q_ASSERT(pendingReply.isFinished());
        if (pendingReply.isError()) {
            qCWarning(timeDateInterfaceCategory).noquote()
                    << tr("Asynchronous call finished with error: %1")
                       .arg(pendingReply.error().message());
            return;
        }
    }

    Q_SCRIPTABLE
    void SetTimezone(QString timezone, bool userInteraction)
    {
        const auto message = call(QDBus::BlockWithGui, {"SetTimezone"},
                                  QVariant::fromValue(timezone),
                                  QVariant::fromValue(userInteraction));
        QDBusPendingReply<> pendingReply = message;
        Q_ASSERT(pendingReply.isFinished());
        if (pendingReply.isError()) {
            qCWarning(timeDateInterfaceCategory).noquote()
                    << tr("Asynchronous call finished with error: %1")
                       .arg(pendingReply.error().message());
            return;
        }
    }

private Q_SLOTS :

    void propertyChanged(QString const & propertyName)
    {
        const auto signature = QStringLiteral("%1Changed()").arg(propertyName);
        const int signalIndex = staticMetaObject.indexOfSignal(QMetaObject::normalizedSignature(qUtf8Printable(signature)).constData());
        if (signalIndex < 0) {
            qCCritical(timeDateInterfaceCategory).noquote()
                    << tr("There is no signal with %1 signature")
                       .arg(signature);
            return;
        }
        const auto signal = staticMetaObject.method(signalIndex);
        if (!signal.invoke(this, Qt::DirectConnection)) {
            qCCritical(timeDateInterfaceCategory).noquote()
                    << tr("Unable to emit %1 signal for %2 property")
                       .arg(signature, propertyName);
        }
    }

    void propertiesChanged(QString interfaceName, QVariantMap changedProperties, QStringList invalidatedProperties)
    {
        if (interfaceName != interface()) {
            return;
        }
        QMapIterator< QString, QVariant > i{changedProperties};
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            propertyChanged(i.next().key());
        }
        for (QString const & invalidatedProperty : invalidatedProperties) {
            propertyChanged(invalidatedProperty);
        }
    }

Q_SIGNALS :

    void CanNTPChanged();
    void LocalRTCChanged();
    void NTPChanged();
    void NTPSynchronizedChanged();
    void RTCTimeUSecChanged();
    void TimeUSecChanged();
    void TimezoneChanged();

private :

    bool CanNTP;
    bool LocalRTC;
    bool NTP;
    bool NTPSynchronized;
    qulonglong RTCTimeUSec;
    qulonglong TimeUSec;
    QString Timezone;

};
```

On my system `qdbus --system org.freedesktop.timedate1 /org/freedesktop/timedate1` gives:

```
method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.GetMachineId()
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.Ping()
method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect()
signal void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged(QString interface, QVariantMap changed_properties, QStringList invalidated_properties)
method QDBusVariant org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get(QString interface, QString property)
method QVariantMap org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll(QString interface)
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set(QString interface, QString property, QDBusVariant value)
property read bool org.freedesktop.timedate1.CanNTP
property read bool org.freedesktop.timedate1.LocalRTC
property read bool org.freedesktop.timedate1.NTP
property read bool org.freedesktop.timedate1.NTPSynchronized
property read qulonglong org.freedesktop.timedate1.RTCTimeUSec
property read qulonglong org.freedesktop.timedate1.TimeUSec
property read QString org.freedesktop.timedate1.Timezone
method void org.freedesktop.timedate1.SetLocalRTC(bool, bool, bool)
method void org.freedesktop.timedate1.SetNTP(bool, bool)
method void org.freedesktop.timedate1.SetTime(qlonglong, bool, bool)
method void org.freedesktop.timedate1.SetTimezone(QString, bool)
```

I consider it is a natural to use `PropertiesChanged` *D-Bus* signal to emit `somePropertyChanged` signals per property. It just connected to `propertiesChanged` dispatcher slot. I need it to emit `somePropertyChanged` signals from *QML*-side singletone (which, in turn, just translates *D-Bus* properties names to *QML* properties names (decapitalizing, conversion from usecs since Epoch to `QDateTime` etc)).

There is requirements in [*Qt Property System*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) to `NOTIFY` signal prototype:

> NOTIFY signals for MEMBER variables must take zero or one parameter, which must be of the same type as the property.

In *QML*-side handler of `somePropertyChanged` signal:

```
Connections {
    target: CppSingleton
    onSomePropertyChanged: {
        if (someProperty) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

symbol `someProperty` is accessible only if `somePropertyChanged` signal is declared unary, not nullary. It is handy to have `someProperty` accessible in signal handler.

When I dispatch `PropertiesChanged` *D-Bus* signal, I have a name of a property. It allows to create signal's prototype string `"somePropertyChanged()"` to get corresponding `QObject`'s method index. Also I have a new value for the property changed. But it is enclosed into `QVariant`. `QMetaMethod::invoke`, in turn, accepts `Q_ARG` values. Therefore I have to use only nullary `*Changed` signals.

Under the hood `Q_ARG` is just a `QArgument`: a pair of typename (`const char *`) and type-erased value (`void *`). Evidently it is variant-concept-like thing. I want to convert `QVariant` to `QGenericArgument`. Is it possible in general case?

`QVariant` has similar to `QGenericArgument`'s constructor: `QVariant::QVariant(int typeId, const void *copy)`. But I want to extract both these values. I think it is enough (with aid of some Qt's RTTI, e.g. `QVariant`'s `const char *typeToName(int typeId)`) to achieve desired.

#### ADDITIONAL:

There are undocumented methods in `QVariant`:

```
void *data();
const void *constData() const;
inline const void *data() const { return constData(); }
```

Maybe I can use them. But problem of ownership is arose in the case.

#### ADDITIONAL 2:

Seems `QGenericArgument` is non-owning being. In conjunction with `Qt::DirectConnection` in-place-like method call I can use `QVariant::data` to get acces to `QVaraint`'s internals.

#### ADDITIONAL 3:

`QDBus` has a mess with `QDBusVariant`/`QVariant` and `QDBusArgument` internal conversions/representation. It seems unpredictable which "typeinfo" for each property is correctly extracted. (It can be solved using undocumented `qdbus_cast< T >(const QVariant &)` cast).

Comment: I will not put it as an answer, as I am not sure that it's what you asked for, but I just did something very similar, may be it will help.. let's say you have QVariant someData[3]; where someData[0] = "Hi"; someData[1] = 1; someData[2] = QVariant::fromValue<double>(3.4); then you can do things like:  QGenericArgument[3]  args; for (int i=0;i<3;i++) { args[i] = QGenericArgument( someData[i].typeName(), someData[i].data() ); } and then to invoke( pObject, args[0], args[1], args[2] ), where signature can be like void method(const QString & v, int n, const QVariant & val);

Comment: Sorry, can't use formatting in comments, also not sure it was what you asked =))

Comment: @evilruff I understand your approach. In the case `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` should use `Qt::ConnectionType::DirectConnection`. It is often not possible.

Comment: Actually I just tried it with BlockingQueuedConnection to QObject in different thread and it worked fine.. yeah you are right.. it will not take an ownership in case of just queued connections.. so data() gets invalid..

Comment: To be honest it's quite interesting, as QueuedConnection suppose to construct a copy which for some reason not happening...

Comment: it's a bit funny, but if you define you own class with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and then use it with queued connection it works perfectly, you can see a copy constructor calls etc.. so other thread gets own copy which is destroyed upon execution

Comment: I made it working =) arguments[j] = Q_ARG(QVariant, values[j]); then it makes a correct copy of a whole QVariant, tried with threads, blocking and non blocking connections..

Comment: So right approach is - if ( argType.isVariant ) { Q_ARG( QVariant, val ) } else { Q_ARG(  val.typeName(), val.data() ) }